# Postgres Truncate Timestamp Truncate to Decisecond

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, trim, truncate

I have a `timestamp` column where I track when an external sensor records a reading. This column goes to the `microsecond`, but I would like to truncate the data to the `decisecond` for grouping purposes.

This [truncate function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) works great, but only allows resolution of `millisecond` or `microsecond`.  I just need to trim my data to the `decisecond` to account for errors in my collection process.

Is there a way to return `timestamp` columns trimmed to the `decisecond`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `Now()` (current time) with column of your choice:

```
select 
  -- current time
  now(), 

  -- current time truncated to minutes
  date_trunc('minute', Now()), 

  -- seconds from timestamp, including decimal part
  extract(seconds from Now()),

  -- seconds truncated to first decimal digit (results in seconds and decisecond)
  trunc((extract(seconds from Now()))::numeric, 1),

  -- add time truncated to minutes and seconds truncated to first decimal digit
  date_trunc('minute', Now()) 
     + interval '1 second' * trunc((extract(seconds from Now()))::numeric, 1)
```

Note that cast to `numeric` is required as `extract()` returns `double precision` and `trunc(x, y)` accepts only `numeric` (see [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html))

With column named `mytime` this would be:

```
  date_trunc('minute', mytime) 
     + interval '1 second' * trunc((extract(seconds from mytime))::numeric, 1)
```

Another option would be to truncate `epoch`:

```
select 
  -- current time
  now(), 

  -- epoch - number of seconds since epoch beginning, including decimal part
  extract(epoch from Now()),

  -- truncated to first decimal digit
  trunc((extract(epoch from Now()))::numeric, 1),

  -- converted back to timestamp
  to_timestamp(trunc((extract(epoch from Now()))::numeric, 1))
```

With column named `mytime` this would be:

```
  to_timestamp(trunc((extract(epoch from mytime))::numeric, 1))
```

Documentation: [`extract`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), [`epoch`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html), [`to_timestamp`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html)